How to catch serialization errors in request pipeline
I have a simple controller method
[HttpPost("Route")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadEmployee(Employee emp)
    {
    ...
    }


Class employee has a Person member that is not nullable:
 public class Employee{
 [System.SerializableAttribute()]
 [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
 public partial class Person{....}
    }


When request body is misssing Person element a xml serialization is caught in the pipeline and the following JSON gets returned with 400 Bad request:
{
    "errors": {
        "": [
            "An error occurred while deserializing input data."
        ]
    },
    "status": 400
}


I am not able to catch this exception in my error handling middleware because it happens on a different thread.
It seems to be a very common situation, does anyone know how to handle it?
I tried writing exception handling middleware.
